# Unable to locate element in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

when I am using the code as follows

```
Select (driver.findElement(By.id("visualizationid"))).selectByVisibleText("Week");
```

I am getting the error such as:

> Unable to locate element:
>
> {"method":"id","selector":"visualizationid"} Command duration or
>   timeout: 30.12 seconds

Can't able to figure out exactly. The HTML code fragment looks like this:

```
<select id="visualizationId" style="width: 120px; display: none;" name="visualization">
    <option value="day">Day</option>
    <option value="week">Week</option>
    <option selected="" value="month">Month</option>
    <option value="quarter">Quarter</option>
    <option value="semester">Semester</option>
    <option value="year">Year</option>
    <!-- ... -->
</select>
```

Comment: Without seeing the HTML markup you're trying to find that element in it's difficult to help

Comment: <select id="visualizationId" style="width: 120px; display: none;" name="visualization">
<option value="day">Day</option>
<option value="week">Week</option>
<option selected="" value="month">Month</option>
<option value="quarter">Quarter</option>
<option value="semester">Semester</option>
<option value="year">Year</option>

Comment: This is the html from this i have created that code

Comment: Is it in an IFrame? If you do just `driver.findElement(By.id("visualizationid"))` on it's own...does it find an element?

Comment: I would imagine your code would only work if the default selected/visible item in the dropdown is "Week".  Is that the case?

Comment: The select list is hidden with `display: none;`. Not sure if the selection will work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled the ID; it's `visualizationId` rather than `visualizationid`. So, capital 'I' in the 'Id'.

Comment: thanks for this correction.. i changed and i run the code but am getting java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Again: Without knowing more about your code it's hard to help. Where do you get the NPE? Is it directly related to the WebElement you're retrieving here?

Comment: Select (driver.findElement(By.id("visualizationId"))).selectByVisibleText("Week");
 driver.findElement(By.id("kpiFilterSubmit")).click();
        }

Comment: And which of the lines throughs the NPE? Also, in the code you posted I can't see any element with the ID "kpiFilterSubmit", so can't say anything about that. Oh, and please add the information to your original post rather than putting it in comments.

Comment: Hi djangofan, In my drop down the default value is month but i tried to select the value "week" and i inspect the element to find by id is id="visualizationId"

Comment: Hi djangofan, In my drop down the default value is month but i tried to select the value "week" and i inspect the element to find by id is id="visualizationId". In the dropdown many options are there in that one 1st day, 2nd week, 3rd month. By default "month" is selected when the page is loaded, but i want to select 2nd option i.e. week

Comment: @Arran: This is an I frame Filter section in side the page, driver.findElement(By.id("visualizationid")) on it's own doesn't able to find an element named week option (In the dropdown many options are there in that 1st day, 2nd week, 3rd month  ... month is the default option)

Comment: Uhm, didn't you mean to add those comments to the original question rather than my reply?